# Pdf form date validation

Tags: javascript, validation, pdf, jspdf

Im trying to make a pdf form validate for a particular date. The form asks for a date and that day can not be more than 3 days ago.

What i have so far is:

```
    var todayDate = new Date();
var today = todayDate.getTime();
//Date minus 3 days in milliseconds
var dayLimit = today - (259200000);
//Entered date is less than current date reject
if (event.getTime < dayLimit) {
app.alert("You must apply for within 3 days")
};
```

But it doesnt work, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious issue is

```
if (event.getTime < dayLimit)
```

Assuming that the script is in the Validation or Calculation event of the field where the date to be tested is displayed, we would first have to create a valid Date object.

Acrobat JavaScript has the `util.scand()` method which creates a Date object from a date string.

So, to create the correct dayLimit value, you will need the Date object, where you can apply the `getTime()` method.